# Ruby no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

please tell me why I have this error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show51", :controller=>"patients"}
```

And after search in select51 I don't get list of patients in index51, I hope I included all files you need to help me with this

Routes:

```
ZOZ::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :refferals

  #17 potwierdzanie rejestracji
  resources :appointments do 
    collection do
        get 'search' 
        get 'search_result'
        get 'to_confirm'
    end
    member do
        put :confirm
    end
  end

  resources :clinics
  resources :doctors

  resources :patients do
    collection do 
        get 'select51'
        get 'index51'
    end
    member do
        get 'show51'
    end
  end

  get "welcome/index2"
  get "welcome/index"

  get 'appointments/create'
  get 'appointments/move' => 'appointments#move'
  post 'appointments/move' => 'appointments#doctors_list'
  get 'appointments/move/:id' => 'appointments#doctor_appointments', as: :doctor_appointments
  get 'appointments/change_appointment/:id' => 'appointments#change_appointment', as: :change_appointment
  get 'appointments/change_doctor_and_appointment/:id' => 'appointments#change_doctor_and_appointment', as: :change_doctor_and_appointment
  get 'appointments/success' => 'appointments#success'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):


  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

patients/index51:

```
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="container">
  <center>
  <h1>Wyniki wyszukiwania:</h1>
    <p>
    Lista pacjentów spełniających podane kryteria w porządku alfabetycznym  
    </br>
    Wybierz odpowiedniego pacjenta aby przejść do kolejnego etapu!
    </p>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Imie</th>
          <th>Nazwisko </th>
          <th>Adres</th>
          <th>Pesel</th>
          <th>Telefon</th>
          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @patients.each do |patient| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= patient.imie %></td>
            <td><%= patient.nazwisko %></td>
            <td><%= patient.adres %></td>
            <td><%= patient.pesel %></td>
            <td><%= patient.telefon %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Wybierz pacjenta', show51_patient_path %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </br>
    <%= link_to 'Powrót do wyszukiwarki', select51_patients_path %>


  </center>
  </div>
```

patients/show51:

```
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="container">
  <center>
    <h3>Dane wybranego pacjenta:</h3>
    <p>
      <strong>Imie:</strong>
      <%= @patient.imie %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Nazwisko:</strong>
      <%= @patient.nazwisko %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Adres pacjenta:</strong>
      <%= @patient.adres %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Pesel pacjenta:</strong>
      <%= @patient.pesel %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Numer telefonu:</strong>
      <%= @patient.telefon %>
    </p>
    <h3>Wybierz typ rejestracji aby przejść dalej:</h3>
    <h4>
    <%= link_to 'Rejestracja na wizytę', doctors_path %>
    </br>
    <%= link_to 'Rejestracja na badanie', clinics_path %>
    </h4>
    </br>
    <%= link_to 'Powrót do wyszukiwarki', select51_patient_path %>

  </center>
  </div>
```

Patients/select51:

```
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="container">
  <center>  
  <h1>Witaj!</h1>

  <p>
  Tutaj możesz zarejestrować pacjenta na:
  </br>
  1. wizytę do wybranego lekarza
  </br>
  2. konkretny typ badania

    <h4>Wyszukaj pacjenta po numerze PESEL:</h4>
    <%= form_tag(index51_patients_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Tutaj wpisz dane" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Przeszukaj bazę", :name => nil %>
    <% end %>

    <h5>
    Uwaga! Możesz wyszukać również po nazwisku pacjenta!
    </br>
    Wystarczy wpisać je w powyższe pole zamiast numeru PESEL
    </br>
    Aby wyświetlić wszystkich pacjentów pozostaw pole puste!
    </h5>
    </p> 
  </center>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController


  # GET /patients
  # GET /patients.json
  def index51
    @patients = Patient.all
    if params[:search]
        @patients = Patient.search(params[:search]).order("created_at ASC")
    else
        @patients = Patient.all.order('created_at ASC')
    end
  end

  # GET /patients/select51
  def select51
    @patients = Patient.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # select51.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @patients }
    end
  end

  # GET /patients/1
  # GET /patients/1.json
  def show51
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    session[:current_patient_id] = @patient.id

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show51.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @patient }
    end
  end

  # GET /patients/new
  # GET /patients/new.json
  def new
    @patient = Patient.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @patient }
    end
  end

  # GET /patients/1/edit
  def edit
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /patients
  # POST /patients.json
  def create
    @patient = Patient.new(params[:patient])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.save
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @patient, status: :created, location: @patient }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /patients/1
  # PUT /patients/1.json
  def update
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.update_attributes(params[:patient])
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /patients/1
  # DELETE /patients/1.json
  def destroy
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @patient.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to patients_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Error:

```
NameError in Patients#index51

Showing D:/p15/app/views/patients/index51.html.erb where line #30 raised:

undefined local variable or method `show51_patients_path' for #<#<Class:0x70fbe10>:0x43b64e0>
Extracted source (around line #30):

27:             <td><%= patient.adres %></td>
28:             <td><%= patient.pesel %></td>
29:             <td><%= patient.telefon %></td>
30:             <td><%= link_to 'Wybierz pacjenta', show51_patients_path %></td>
31:           </tr>
32:         <% end %>
33:       </tbody>
```

Comment: What about controller? It is required.

Comment: then undefined local variable or method `show51_patients_path'

Comment: @zishe added controller

Comment: also in rake routes show51_patient_path

Comment: Can you include the full error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to 'Wybierz pacjenta', show51_patient_path %></td>
```

should be

```
<td><%= link_to 'Wybierz pacjenta', show51_patient_path(patient) %></td>
```

Comment: @Martin could you help me with problem with session ?;> I search for patient in patients/select51.html.erb, then in patients/index51.html.erb I choose one, where I should put     patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
session[:current_patient_id] = patient.id
?

Comment: If you have another problem, better to make it another question (not simple to read/answers in comments, and you have better chance to get an answer from other people, too). If you are really starting with Rails, I would advice you to start with a tutorial like the one from Michael Hartl

Comment: Maybe save this in show and automatically redirect?

Comment: I know but I cannot post again :( I have just one more problem with this sessions :)